# Como introducir dos datos a una variable para su posterior operación y devolución en pantalla con javascript

Tags: javascript

Bueno, el caso es que quiero calcular el área de un cuadrado ( alto * base) introduciendo yo mismo los valores "alto" y "base" mediante un **prompt** que se ejecuta en cuanto se abre la página. Esto es lo que tengo, pero no consigo saber que hacer para que funcione:

```
function area(alto, base) {
    return (alto * base);
}

var result = prompt("Cuanto mide el Alto");
var result2 = prompt("Cuando mi de la Base");
var alt=area(result);
var bs=area(result2);
document.write("El área del cuadrado es : " + );
```

Como podéis ver, intento introducir los valores correspondientes mediante el `prompt` y que la función realice la operación para que después me lo desvuelva con un **document.write**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error más visible es los elementos `<br>` en su `script` , no veo necesario su uso además es imposible hacerlo así directamente.

También su función `area` **recibe dos parámetros** y usted solo le envía `1` en cada llamada, lo cuál es incorrecto , además es una mala practica emplear `document.write` , sería mejor tener un elemento en el documento y añadir ahí el resultado.

```js
function area(alto, base) {
    return (alto * base);
}

var alt = prompt("Cuanto mide el Alto"); // solicitamos el alto
var base = prompt("Cuando mi de la Base");// solicitamos la base
// llamamos a la función pasando los 2 valores
var area =area(alt,base);

//añadimos al dom el elemento con id resultado
document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = "El área del cuadrado es : " + area;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

> ¿Cómo funciona la última línea que es la que muestra el resultado?

Con la linea se pueden separar en dos partes

- `document.getElementById('resultado')` , aquí lo que se hace es obtener la referencia del elemento del `dom`, que tenga como atributo el `id` *resultado* , para el ejemplo es un `div`
- `.innerText = "El área del cuadrado es : " + area;` ,  en esta parte se asigna el texto a mostrar dentro del elemento `div` , para el ejemplo simplemente el resultado con un texto adicional ,

Comment: Perdón, coloqué los `<br>` para los saltos de línea pues no sabia colocar código en la pregunta. Mi código va sin ellos, lo actualizaré enseguida. Bueno, el caso es que necesito hacerlo de tal forma que según abro la página me aparezcan dos `prompt` en los que yo introduciré los valores correspondientes. Al mismo tiempo, la función cogerá estos valores y operará con ellos para, finalmente, visualizar con `document.write` el resultado de la operación.

Comment: @KelvinMacay eso hace mi respuesta. revise y comenté si le ayudó o tiene dudas de algo.

Comment: Sí, tengo una duda. **¿Cómo funciona la última línea que es la que muestra el resultado?**. Aún no he estudiado eso y no la entiendo. Por eso hacía el código con `document.write`.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @KelvinMacay añadí una pequeña descripción con respecto a su pregunta, me alegro que haya ayudado. Saludos.